# How does apache spark works?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I am testing this framework specifically the SQL module with the java API. Running it as standalone in java, I have better results (even running in the same machine) then pure sql (running over pgadmin).

Executing exactly the same query in the same bd (postgres 9.4 and 9.5), sparks is almost 5 x faster, below is my code:

```
private static final JavaSparkContext sc =
            new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf()
                    .setAppName("SparkJdbc").setMaster("local[*]"));

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append(" my query ");

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection("org.postgresql.Driver", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb", "user", "pass");
        JdbcRDD<Object[]> jdbcRDD = new JdbcRDD<>(sc.sc(), dbConnection, sql.toString(),
                              1, 1000000000, 20, new MapResult(), ClassManifestFactory$.MODULE$.fromClass(Object[].class));

        JavaRDD<Object[]> javaRDD = JavaRDD.fromRDD(jdbcRDD, ClassManifestFactory$.MODULE$.fromClass(Object[].class));

//        javaRDD.map((final Object[] record) -> {
//            StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
//            for (Object o : record) {
//                line.append(o != null ? o.toString() : "").append(",");
//            }
//            return line.toString();
//        }).collect().forEach(rec -> System.out.println(rec));

        System.out.println("Total: " + javaRDD.count());
        System.out.println("Total time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time));

    }
```

Even if I uncomment the code to print the results to the console, it still running faster.

I am wondering how can it be faster, if the source (bd) is the same, can anyone explain it? Maybe using parallel query?

**EDIT:** There is a relevant information about the postgres process, in standby, the postgres uses 12 process and running the query over pgadmin, the number does not change, over spark, it up to 20, that means probably spark uses some parallel mechanism to do the job.